# Passing OpenMP flag for all files affects results

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am restructuring a complex numerical Fortran code to use CMake. I realized that, when requested, the OpenMP flag is passed to all files, even those that do not need it (i.e. no `omp` constructs).

Passing the OpenMP flag to only files that need it generates a binary that eventually does not produces exactly the same numerical results, compared with passing the OpenMP flag to all files. Which approach should be used then?

I am still narrowing down the origin of that difference, and cannot give a MWE for now.

Comment: Using OpenMP often has an impact on the optimisations that a compiler makes.  The hand-wavy explanation is that some optimisations a compiler would otherwise make are invalid for OpenMP loops (in particular) so they are not made. You are not specific about how, and how much, the results are affected, and if it's down in the low order digits of the results it may just be a difference in the order of operations such as computing running totals.   That's, a temporary 'answer' while you sort out an MWE.  And when you update your question, be specific about how the results are affected.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The absolute difference is in the order of magnitude of 10⁻⁴ for floating point results. Not high, but enough to be caught on integration tests.

Comment: And relative differences?  And please don't make 'answer' in another comment, that is important stuff and ought to be in your question.  Along with the MWE ...